# knockout check all checkboxes in table column

Tags: foreach, knockout.js

I am new to knockout and trying to implement a table with the first column as a checkbox. When I click the header the whole column should get checked / unchecked. At the moment, it works when I click table rows (all rows get checked/unchecked) but not on table header. Please let me know what is wrong with my code! Here is parts of my code :

````
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: selectAll"></th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
        
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: DocumentRows">
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: $parent.IsSelected"></td>
             <td><data-bind="text: Notes"></td>
</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        
       // Script.ts
        
        ```
        define(['knockout', 'jquery', 'text!./Template'], (ko, $, htmlString) => {
        //Document
        class Document {
                Id: KnockoutObservable<number>;      
                Notes: KnockoutObservable<string>;        
                constructor(data?) {
                    this.Id = ko.observable(0);          
                    this.Notes = ko.observable("").extend({ defaultValue: "" });            
                    if (data != null) {
                        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
                    }
                }        
            };
        
        
        //DocumentS VIEW MODEL
        class DocumentsViewModel {
        DocumentRows: KnockoutObservableArray<Document>;
        IsSelected: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
               
        constructor(params) {
        this.DocumentRows = ko.observableArray([]);
        this.IsSelected = ko.observable(false);//
        this.InitComputed();       
               this.Load();
        }
        InitComputed = () => {
        selectAll = (Document: DocumentsViewModel) => {      
                    var doc = Document.DocumentRows;           
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(doc(), function (item) {
                        item.IsSelected(true);
                    });
                }
        
        Load = () => {
                    DocumentsApiService.GetDocumentList(this);
                }
        
        }
        
        //API SERVICE
        class DocumentsApiService {
                static GetDocumentList = (model: DocumentsViewModel) => {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: buildUrl(model.LoadListURL, { 'id': model.ObjectId(), 'additionalId': model.AdditionalId() }),
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: ko.mapping.toJSON(model.Filter),
                        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                    }).done(allData => {
                        var mapped = ko.mapping.fromJS(allData, DocumentsMapping);
                        model.DocumentRows(mapped.DocumentRows());
                        model.Filter.TotalCount(mapped.TotalCount());
                        model.Filter.PageIndex(mapped.Filter.PageIndex());
                        CalcCountTableStatus(model.Filter.PageIndex(), model.Filter.PageSize(), model.Filter.TotalCount(), 'documents-count-status-line');
                    }).fail(data => {
                        TSCore.OnFailure(data);
                    });
                }
        }
        
            return { viewModel: DocumentsViewModel, template: htmlString }
        });
        ```
````

Answer (score 1):

When implementing such a selection feature, usually there are two approaches.

#### Have an `isSelected` boolean observable at the `Document` level

Put the `isSelected` observable on the `Document` model and no on the `DocumentsViewModel`, because each document must hold the information whether it's selected or not.

I guess you were trying to implement this approach, but at first glance, you do not have the `IsSelected` at the right place. Also, if you move `IsSelected` to the document, then in you view do not use `$parent.IsSelected`, but just `IsSelected`.

#### Maintain a `selectedDocuments` observable array of documents at the `DocumentsViewModel` level

This way you can have an observable array of all the currently selected documents, and maintain that when selecting all of them (like push all the rows to the selection)

In your view, you must use a parent reference to determine whether the document is selected similar to for example `$parent.selectedDocuments.indexOf($data) >= 0`.

I'll not cover all the pros and cons of the two approach for now, but I suggest you use the first one, if you can extend your document model with an `IsSelected` observable.

#### Other notes

It's not quite clear what you want to achieve with the `InitComputeds` stuff. Why don't you just have these actions as functions on your viewmodel class like

```
public selectAll(): void {      
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.DocumentRows(), function (item) {
        item.IsSelected(true);
    });
}
```

If you use this syntax, you must bind the function at the view level like `$data.selectAll.bind($data)`. If you do not want that, and you want just purely `selectAll`, then you can use arrow function as a field syntax like this.

```
public selectAll = ():void => {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.DocumentRows(), function (item) {
        item.IsSelected(true);
    });
}
```

Hope I could give some valuable hints.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering this - I have made the changes as per your suggestion and it works now. Need to make a few more tweaks to get column header checked/unchecked as right now it remains unchecked for some reason.

Comment: Glad I could help. You can probably create a computed which would tell you whether all the items are selected or not. You could bind this to the header checkbox.

Comment: So, I changed the tbody to this  <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected"></td>

Comment: any further help will be much appreciated @Zoltán Tamási

Comment: @Anna it's quite hard to tell the issue from here. Please prepare a sample from your code in jsfiddle for example, and I'll try to have a look then.

Answer (score 0):

So, after changes
Table header:

```
<th><input type="checkbox" data-bind="click: selectAll, checked: selectedAll"></th>
```

Table body:

```
 <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsSelected"></td>
```

Script:

```
    //Document
class Document {
    Id: KnockoutObservable<number>;        
    IsSelected: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
    constructor(data?) {
        this.Id = ko.observable(0);
        this.Notes = ko.observable("").extend({ defaultValue: "" });          
        this.IsSelected = ko.observable(false);
        if (data != null) {
            ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, this);
        }
    }
};
```

//DocumentS VIEW MODEL

```
     class DocumentsViewModel {
    selectedAll: KnockoutObservable<boolean>;
  constructor(params) {
 this.selectedAll = ko.observable(false);
}
 InitComputed = () => {
this.selectedAll = ko.pureComputed({
                read: function () {
                    return this.selectedIds().length === this.DocumentRows().length;
                },
                write: function (value) {
                    this.selectedIds(value ? this.DocumentRows.slice(0) : []);
                },
                owner: this
            }
     selectAll = (): void => {
                if (this.selectedIds().length > 0) {
                    this.selectedIds.removeAll();
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.DocumentRows(), function (item) {
                        item.IsSelected(false);
                    });
                } else {
                    ko.utils.arrayPushAll(this.selectedIds(), this.DocumentRows())
                    ko.utils.arrayForEach(this.DocumentRows(), function (item) {
                        item.IsSelected(true);
                    });
                }
            }
    }
```

It doesn't show the header to be checked when all rows are checked or unchecked when all are unchecked. Any pointers where I am going wrong please?